# Add Refrence In VisualStudio

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project. I want to add a reference to it. But will it still work if I copy the program to another computer? in other words, when adding a reference it requires a path. if I run it on another computer, The path will change...
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work, you just should copy the program together with references in same directory.

Usually Visual Studio will do that whenever you build project.

[image]

Comment: For example, if reference.dll path is "C:\Files\ProjectDirectory\" when I copy it to new system it will be "D:\Files\ProjectDirectory". Will this work?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can even rename the folder with your app. Just one thing required - your reference should be in same directory with your app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the "Copy Local = true" is set in the reference properties. 
The reference dll's would have moved to the target directory where your exe resides. 
While moving the program to new system, do copy the entire thing along with bin folder, then it should all work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Official references guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019)

> ### **References to shared components at run time**
>
> At run time, components must be either in the output path of the project or in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). If the project contains a reference to an object that is not in one of these locations, you must copy the reference to the output path of the project when you build the project. The [CopyLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcprojectreference.copylocal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_VCProjectEngine_VCProjectReference_CopyLocal) property indicates whether this copy has to be made. If the value is True, the reference is copied to the project directory when you build the project. If the value is False, the reference is not copied.

### Warning - It will not copy if it's in the GAC

There is a case where the reference will not be copied by default

> By default, the CopyLocal property is set to False if the assembly or component is in the global assembly cache **([GAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac))** or is a framework component. Otherwise, the value is set to **True**. Project-to-project references are always set to **True**.

In this case you can right click on the file and set the file to true manually after adding the reference:
[image: Set local copy to true]